# How to make mod_rewrite silently redirect and pass parameter to index when the {REQUEST_FILENAME} is an existing directory or file

Tags: file, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

Synopsis:

localhost/root/admin is an existing folder
I want /root/admin to go to /root/index.php?url=admin without changing the url in the address bar.

The **only** except is if the requested file is an image

This is what I have written for the .htaccess file in localhost/root to try and do all this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*\.(png|jpg|gif))$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What this does instead is redirect localhost/root/admin to localhost/root/index.php and changes the url in the address bar to localhost/root/admin/?url=admin.

It will only not do this if I add a trailing slash (/) onto "admin".

I know that, on my mac laptop, this mod_rewrite code does exactly what it is meant to, but only when running it in the "Sites" folder and not in the localhost htdocs folder.

Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the "PT" flag to prevent an actual redirect. PT (Passthrough) means that Apache redirects the resource served internally, but the browser sees the same URL. (See the Apache wiki for more details: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/PT)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*\.(png|jpg|gif))$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Note the only change was to add the flag. I tested this on my server and saw the behavior that I think you want.

Comment: Same issue as before, even with the PT flag. I have an index.php file at "localhost/root/index.php" and another index.php at "localhost/root/admin/index.php". If I go to "localhost/root/admin" (not localhost/root/admin/) it sends me the info from "localhost/root", like it should, but changes my address bar to "localhost/root/admin/?url=admin". On top of that, with your code, "localhost/root/admin/index.php" will not redirect me at all but I want **EVERY** request to go to "localhost/root/index.php" except images. Is it possible that localhost is interfering with my goal?

Comment: Hm. Could you post your current .htaccess file? And double-check that here is no .htaccess one directory up (and no other rewrite rules in your apache configuration).